# How do I remove duplicates of the same image in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-3, duplicates

I recently imported a large library into Lightroom, I've been going through it and have found several duplicates of the same pictures. They might be in different folders as well. Is there an easy way to remove duplicates? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst I can't recommend this personally, I did stumble across this Lightroom Plugin the other day:
http://www.lightroom-plugins.com/DupesIndex.php

Answer (score 1):

My go-to method of finding exact dupes is this command line on windows with cygwin or linux.

```
find /path/to/files/ -name "*.file-extension" -exec md5sum -b {} \; |sort|uniq -w 32 -c|sort -n
```

The bottom of the list will show the dupe md5 hashed with the path to the first instance of the file.

You can find all copies of that file with:

```
find /path/to/files/ -name "*.file-extension" -exec md5sum -b {} \;| grep "MD5HASHCODEHERE"
```

Where MD5HASHCODEHERE is the 32 char long code.

I once did this on 650,000 files to find all the version of the same 8 gif files and it took less than an hour. I don't know if OSX has md5sum installed by default. I can offer a OSX version if needed.

No idea if this is helpful.

Comment: uniq -w option is not available in OSX. md5 is installed or md5sum can be installed through homebrew (md5sha1sum).

Answer (score 1):

The Teekesselchen add-on works well too.

- Add-on's web site: http://www.bungenstock.de/teekesselchen/
- Listing on Adobe: https://creative.adobe.com/addons/products/2652